# Probability of overlapping events in Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

There are two types of arriving requests to an object, either (S)hared or (E)xclusive. There can be multiple `S` locks at a given time on the item (i.e. `S` locks are compatible with each other), while there can be only **one** `E` lock and **no** `S` lock (i.e. exclusive locks are incompatible with both other exclusive and shared locks). Each request takes on average `t` seconds. When a new incoming request is received and it cannot be granted, it fails.

Let's assume that the assumptions for the Poisson distribution hold here and both request types are Poisson processes ($\lambda_S$ and $\lambda_E$ for the rate of shared and exclusive locks, respectively).  How can I find the number of requests that fail?

---

*(from this point on, things can be horribly wrong)*

What I have so far:

$$P(\text{$k$ reqs of type $S$})=\frac{e^{-{\lambda_S} } {\lambda_S}^k }{k!}$$

$$P(\text{$k$ reqs of type $E$})=\frac{e^{-{\lambda_E} } {\lambda_E}^k }{k!}$$

So, we will have:

$$P(\text{an $S$ will be granted}) = P(\text{there exists $0$ of $E$} ) = e^{-{\lambda_E} }$$

$$P(\text{an $E$ will be granted}) = P(\text{there exists $0$ of $E$}) \cdot P(\text{there exists $0$ of $S$}) =  e^{-{\lambda_E} } \cdot e^{-{\lambda_S} }$$

And then to get the expected value of success, we will weigh these two probabilities by their corresponding arrival rates.

I think my calculations are not correct, and I am confused how to use $t$, the average length of each request.

Comment: Do you mean that the "shared" and "exclusive" requests each follow a Poisson *process*?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes. the two request types are both Poisson processes.

Comment: Where you say "each request takes an average of $t$ seconds", do you mean that's how long the lock exists?

Comment: If the rate at which requests of type $S$ arrive is $\lambda_S,$ then the number of requests of type $S$ that arrive during an interval of time of length $u$ is Poisson-distributed with expected value $\lambda_S u,$ not with expected value $\lambda_S. \qquad$

Comment: $$\Pr(\text{0 requests of type $E$ arrive before time $u$}) = e^{-\lambda_E u}.$$ However, how many such locks exist at a given time depends on how long a lock lasts.